# Is there a way to intercept a child process's output, or change from "inherit" to "piped" after the first input to stdin?

Tags: command-line, rust

I'm trying do do this:

```sh
# Call `mysql` from inside a running container named "db"

cargo run my-command "docker exec -it db mysql -u user -p my-database"
```

This will result in the `mysql` command displaying a password prompt and waiting for user input, which is what I want. However, upon typing the password and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, all further output from the child process should be collected, but hidden from the user.

I tried this

```rust
let args = ["docker", "exec", "-it", "db", "mysql", "-u", "user", "-p"];

// `sudo` only used for testing. It's needed for docker,
// but `sudo cargo run ...` doesn't work
let cmd = process::Command::new("sudo")
    .args(&args)
    .spawn() // stdout will be inherited
    .expect("external cmd failed.")
    .wait_with_output()?;
```

This waits for the child to finish and *then* prints all the output with no way to filter it.

I tried to check for input before waiting on the child to finish but it panics:

```rust
let mut cmd = process::Command::new("sudo")
    .args(&args)
    .spawn()
    .expect("external cmd failed.");

let mut s = String::new();
// Trying to inspect the stdout for the if check below,
// but this will panic
let mut out = cmd.stdout.take().unwrap();
out.read_to_string(&mut s);

if s.contains("password") {
    // From now on, don't display child's stdout
}

let output = cmd.wait_with_output()?;

let result = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);

// do something with the result
```

The next thing I tried was

```rust
let mut cmd = process::Command::new("sudo")
    .args(&args)
    .stdout(process::Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .expect("external cmd failed.");

let output = cmd.wait_with_output()?;
```

This gets close as the output is captured and hidden. However, while the user can technically type the password, and it will proceed with the command, the "Enter password:" prompt is hidden, so the user may not know they can indeed enter a password.

Comment: What does "inject some other arguments (not shown) into the quoted command" mean? You started a command `docker exec -it db mysql -u user -p my-database`, and now you want it to change to `docker exec -it db mysql -u user -p my-database some other args` after it has already started?

Comment: The quoted command is what the user will supply, but it's incomplete. The rust program will append some other arguments to the quoted command before starting it. In the case of the example, it'd be other mysql specific options.

Comment: That's not how things work. You can't add arguments after starting the process.

Comment: I appreciate your interest in this question muru, and I'd like to clear any confusion. I'm appending the args *before* the child process starts, and I'm doing so successfully. However, that's just a contextual detail, if that. The question is not about that, but about **showing child output until the first input, and hiding all further child output** while the rust program still has access to it.

Comment: Then your paragraph after the first code block is rather weird and misleading. Specifically: "However, upon typing the password and pressing enter, the Rust program should inject some other arguments (not shown) into the quoted command"  implies you're trying to add arguments after input. At any rate, then this seems like a Rust programming problem than anything Unix-y. Your third code block is pretty much what I'd do in C, C++, Python, bash, etc. If it panics, you have a Rust-specific problem here, and should ask on [so].